# DotNetNuke adds wrong module to page

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I've deployed DotNetNuke 07.03.02 to Azure using Azure's own wizard - worked fine. Been using DNN for years on personal server without issues.

However, when I try to add a module to a page (i.e regular editing) DNN adds the **wrong module** to the page; seemingly FirstOrDefault from the list of installed modules.

I.E, I want to add the "HTML" module (or any other) to a page but instead I get the "Banners" module. If I then uninstall the the Banners module it now adds the "Modules list" module.

See below example, where I'm editing the "About" page of my site and have tried to add the HTML module.

I hope anyone with insight into DNN (on Azure) can provide info. I am a .Net developer, but have so far had no reason to dig into DNN's inner workings.

[image: editing page in DNN]

Comment: Is this a fresh install, or an upgrade?

Comment: it was a fresh install on Azure.
then I tried to upgrade (by uploading upgrade files through FTP), but the issue remained.
I've of course tried different browsers and so on

Comment: Any javascript errors?

Comment: None that I can see in Chrome's console, but it's been a long time since I debugged web.
You can try it for yourself now: user/pass "stackoverflow"
http://hlinteractive.azurewebsites.net/Login

Comment: Check your event logs, I see a 500 error when I try to change the category to insert on the page to "all categories" hunt this down and Im sure your problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fresh install of DNN on Azure and installed a skin. Works fine.

I notice the ribbon look different now, so I guess there's a new stable of DNN.

It works well anyway, so case closed.